# Custom StartActivity taking long time to load new Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin

I am trying to call a new activity from my current one dynamically. So I created an object class that taking activity, class, and bundle as optional.

```
object ActivityHelper {

    fun start(context: Context, activity: Class<out BaseCompatActivity>, extras: Bundle? = null) {
        val intent = Intent(context, activity)
        extras?.let {
            intent.putExtras(extras)
        } ?: run {
            intent.putExtra("flag", context.javaClass.getSimpleName())
        }
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

after that, I am calling this from all activities like this

```
    ActivityHelper.start(this, Activity::class.java, extras)
```

But I noticed it makes the app loading time slower than before. Am I doing it correctly? or is it bad idea to start activity like this?

Comment: slower activity creation means you have ton of stuffs going on in `onCreate` or `onStart` or `onResume` of Activity you are trying to start.

Comment: @RahulKumar so it's not because of the way I'm starting the activity?

Comment: yes. typically its the case. try taking everything off main thread to background thread and use main thread to update ui only. Do not do calculation or any other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

On the activity you are trying to load, hide views in layout by default. onResume you can delay and then set the view visibility to true. If your UI layout is complex or you are using some library for anim, it would take more time to start.